# What are the constraints on the value returned by `id()`

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, hash

The [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) only has this to say:

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is
> guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its
> lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same
> id() value.
>
> CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in
> memory.

Which doesn't bound the returned integer, not does it have anything to say about how or if it varies on different OS.

I assume some virtual memory addresses won't ever be returned, and also assume it is different on 32 vs 64 bit systems, and also on Win/Linux/OSX.

Is there an equivalent `os` function that is more predictable?